# Fatal error: session_start()

Tags: session, whmcs

i installed WHMCS on my new direct admin host and i get this Error.

```
Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: files (path: ) in /home/admin/domains/*****/public_html/my/includes/classes/WHMCS/Session.php on line 0
```

please any tips can be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the session couldn't be written to the file system.

Check the session.save_path in your php.ini is set correctly. It would be set to /tmp for example. But better to ask your hosting company for the right path, as it might imply security issues.